# Powershell Joining objects that have been picked up from an xml

Tags: xml, powershell

I have the following:

```
$XPath = "//INVOICEHEADER"
$XPath2 = "//FILE"
# path where we need to look for the xml. * means all files that end in .xml
$Path = "$sourcelocation\*.xml"

# Select-Xml -Path $Path -XPath $Xpath | 
# Select-Object -EA SilentlyContinue -ExpandProperty Node |
# # export results append to the file NNUH.csv
# Export-Csv -append -Path $resultfilepathtemp -NoTypeInformation 
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path | 

ForEach-Object {
    $xml = Select-Xml -Path $_.FullName -XPath $Xpath
    $results = Select-Object -InputObject $Xml -EA SilentlyContinue -ExpandProperty Node
    # Write-Output $results
    $xml = Select-Xml -Path $_.FullName -XPath $Xpath2 
    $results2 = Select-Object -InputObject $Xml -EA SilentlyContinue -ExpandProperty Node

    # Need to join results together

    Export-Csv -InputObject $results -append -Path $resultfilepathtemp -NoTypeInformation 
}
```

I'm trying to join two objects that I have picked up from an .xml.  Struggling on how to get this to output to a file.  The .xml looks like this:

```
XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<INVOICEIMPORT TYPE="INVOICE">
  <INVOICES>
    <INVOICE>
      <INVOICEHEADER>
        <CATEGORY>1</CATEGORY>
        <PURCHASEORDERNO>AA00000</PURCHASEORDERNO>
        <OURREF>AA00000</OURREF>
        <ATTRIB2>Client name</ATTRIB2>
        <ATTRIB3>Address</ATTRIB3>
        <SUPPLIERREF>1000000000</SUPPLIERREF>
        <INVOICEDATE>20200302</INVOICEDATE>
        <ARRIVAL>20200401</ARRIVAL>
        <AMOUNT>100,401.20</AMOUNT>
        <VATAMOUNT>13,900.20</VATAMOUNT>
        <CURRENCY.CURRENCYID>GBP</CURRENCY.CURRENCYID>
        <CLIENT.CODE>9999</CLIENT.CODE>
        <ITVNCODE>No supplier found</ITVNCODE>
      </INVOICEHEADER>
      <FILES>
        <FILE>
          <TRANSACTIONTYPE>X104</TRANSACTIONTYPE>
          <FULLFILENAME>PP_XXXX_00001.pdf</FULLFILENAME>
          <PAGENUMBER>1</PAGENUMBER>
        </FILE>
      </FILES>
    </INVOICE>
  </INVOICES>
</INVOICEIMPORT>
```

and the output should be in a similar format as:

```
"CATEGORY","PURCHASEORDERNO","OURREF","ATTRIB2","ATTRIB3","SUPPLIERREF","INVOICEDATE","ARRIVAL","AMOUNT","VATAMOUNT","CURRENCY.CURRENCYID","CLIENT.CODE","ITVNCODE","TRANSACTIONTYPE","FULLTIMENAME","PAGENUMBER"
"1","AA00000","AA00000","Client name","Address","1000000000","20200302","20200401","100,401.20","13,900.20","GBP","9999","No supplier found","X104","PP_XXXX_00001.pdf","1"
```

Think I am getting close with this as I am new to PowerShell (just over a week).  I have PowerShell 5.1 installed on the server which the code will eventually be run on.  I have tried to join them:

```
# Need to join results together
     $endresult = $results + $results2
    Export-Csv -InputObject $endresult -append -Path $resultfilepathtemp -NoTypeInformation
```

But I get an error message:

```
Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At C:\Client\ClientX.ps1:74 char:29
+     Export-Csv -InputObject $rpc -append -Path $resultfilepathtemp -N ...
+                             ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCo 
   mmand
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$results` and  `$results2` variables contain (potentially *arrays of*) [`System.Xml.XmlElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlElement) instances.

- If the variables contains *arrays* (if your input XML has multiple `INVOICE` elements, which seems likely):

  - Using `+` with arrays concatenates them (creates a new array that contains all elements of the LHS array, followed by all elements of the RHS array) - this won't do what you want, which is to *merge* the child elements from *corresponding* XML elements.
- If the variables contains *scalars* (an `XmlElement` instance each):

  - Using `+` *fails*, because `XmlElement` doesn't define an overload for the `+` operator.

---

To get the desired output:

- You must process the arrays *in element pairs*.
- For each pair, you must *merge* the input `XmlElement`s to form an element that contains the *union* of the respective child nodes.
- Then you can export the merged elements to a CSV file with `Export-Csv`.

```
$XPath = "//INVOICEHEADER"
$XPath2 = "//FILE"
$Path = "$sourcelocation\*.xml"

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path | 
  ForEach-Object {

    # Load and parse the XML file once.
    [xml] $xml = Get-Content -Raw $_.FullName

    # Run the XPath queries.
    $results = $xml.SelectNodes($XPath)
    $results2 = $xml.SelectNodes($XPath2)

    # Process the results in pairs:
    # Create a new element containing the union of the child elements.
    foreach ($i in 0..($results.Count-1)) {
      # Append the child nodes of the RHS array element to the LHS
      # array element.
      # NOTE: @(...) ensures that the child nodes are collected in an aux.
      #       array up front; without that, the .AppendChild() calls would
      #       interfere with the enumeration of .ChildNodes.
      foreach ($child in @($results2[$i].ChildNodes)) {
        $null = $results[$i].AppendChild($child)
      }
      # Output the merged element.
      $results[$i]
    }

  } | Export-Csv -Path $resultfilepathtemp -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hi Mklement!.  that piece of code does wonders!.  I was going down the route of putting out two different csv files and then merging them, but this method I did think would be more cleaner and faster to run.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it was helpful, @CarlLam.